# XCode4 update to iOS5 release

Tags: xcode4, ios5

How do I update my **snow leopard** version of Xcode from iOS 4.3 to iOS 5.0? I got my device upgraded to iOS5, but now xcode nags at me saying I need to downgrade it to 4.3 or below...

I found this link on the apple dev center, however it tells me "access denied, contact adc..."

http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_with_ios_5_sdk/xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg

The link in the Mac App store only takes me to the Lion version of the xcode 4.2....

**Update: It turns out you need to accept more pages of agreements on the iOS development portal before they will let you download anything. It is highlighted in yellow towards the top of the screen**

Comment: i'm having the same problem but i can't find those agreements. no yellow highlights or anything.

Comment: go to your "Member Center" (far top right of the window) the Agreement Addendums are shown there. Bart-Jan.

Answer (score 0):

No explanation behind the cause of the error, but here's one fix:

1) Go to http://developer.apple.com/downloads

2) Search for Xcode

Download Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard.